# Get eclipse plugin for JAR distribution

Tags: eclipse

I want to use io.reactivex rxjava in Eclipse RCP application.
What is the best way to get it as eclipse plugin, including a source plugin?
Is there a project doing those convertions?
It is not included into the eclipse/orbit.
Or do i need to do it on my own?

Frank

Answer (score 0):

If the original provider is not making an OSGI ready bundle for you (i.e. adding in the few extra bits to the MANIFEST.MF), you can make your own bundle with the Eclipse Bundle Recipes (EBR).

As of writing this (Oct 2015) Eclipse Orbit is currently moving to EBR for new bundles as they are packaged up. But you can do your own. Hopefully by time time some future person reads this, the EBR website will be a bit more complete https://www.eclipse.org/ebr/, but for now these slides and blog posts should get you started:

- https://www.eclipsecon.org/na2015/sites/default/files/slides/Tasty%20Recipes%20for%20OSGi%20Bundles.pdf
- http://wagenknecht.org/blog/archives/2014/02/eclipse-bundle-recipes.html

The basic idea is you need to connect it up to Maven with a [pom.xml](https://github.com/eclipse/ebr/blob/master/recipes/apache/commons/org.apache.commons.codec_1.9.0/pom.xml) that looks a little like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>apache-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>org.apache.commons.codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-bundle-recipe</packaging>
  <name>Apache Commons Codec</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This works along with the [bnd](https://github.com/eclipse/ebr/blob/master/recipes/apache/commons/org.apache.commons.codec_1.9.0/osgi.bnd) file that looks a little like this:

```
package-version=${version;===;${Bundle-Version}}

Export-Package: \
 *.internal*;x-internal:=true;version="${package-version}", \
 *.impl*;x-internal:=true;version="${package-version}", \
 *;version="${package-version}"

Import-Package: \
 *
```

And there you go, with the above and a simple maven invocation, you have an OSGI bundle to use with your Eclipse RCP application.

Note that you will probably come across the question of what to name the bundle you are creating, Eclipse has some guidelines that may help: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Bundle_Naming